# What can i do to fix Undefined array key 0 without adding @ to suppres the error

Tags: arrays, key, undefined, osclass

- Since upgrade to php 8.1 i am having a Undefined array key 0 in error log.
  The line that shows the error is:
      `if(osc_subdomain_type() == 'category' && $cat[0]['s_slug'] != osc_subdomain_slug() || osc_subdomain_type() != 'category') { $category = $cat[0];`

By putting the @ sign the error is suppressed but not solved.... How can i fix this? All help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is not much diff between using @ and different approach, however if you want to be 100% perfect, use:

```
if(osc_subdomain_type() == 'category' && isset($cat[0]) && $cat[0]['s_slug'] != osc_subdomain_slug() || osc_subdomain_type() != 'category') {
```

$category = isset($cat[0]) ? $cat[0] : array();
}